# How to update a module's view programmatically using hook_update_n?

Tags: 7, views, updating

We're writing some update functions for a custom module. This custom module provides some views:

```
/**
 * Implements hook_views_default_views().
 */
function mymodule_views_default_views() {
  $views_dir = drupal_get_path('module', 'mymodule') . '/views';
  $views_files = scandir($views_dir);
  $views = array();
  foreach ($views_files as $filename) {
    if (substr($filename, -4) == '.inc') {
      include_once $views_dir . '/' . $filename;
    }
  }
  return $views;
}
```

There are several `.inc` files from the view export ui and all those views are provided.

**Now:** some of those views should be updated. We usually just export and re-import them using the view ui (and override existing views). We wondered, **how would this be possible programmatically**? How to tell views which files to import again and override?

```
function mmodule_update_7001() {
  // what goes here?
}
```

Thanks for any ideas!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

we ended up adding the following code inside the `update_n` function:

```
  $views_dir = drupal_get_path('module', 'mymodule') . '/views';
  $views_files = scandir($views_dir);
  $views = array();
  foreach ($views_files as $filename) {
    if (substr($filename, -4) == '.inc') {
      include_once $views_dir . '/' . $filename;
      if (isset($view) && is_object($view)) {
        views_save_view($view);
      }
    }
  }
```